# using recevier in service

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm trying to count time that user is using a phone, so i used receiver
it got registered in MainActivity then i am starting TimeService which is registring receiver too so it can work even if user is in other activity or app.

MainActivity

```
 private void registerScreenReceiver(){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
```

TimeService

```
public class TimeService extends Service {
//
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // REGISTER RECEIVER THAT HANDLES SCREEN ON AND SCREEN OFF LOGIC
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int start_id) {
        boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
        if (!screenOn) {
            Log.e("SERVICE","ON");

        } else {

            Log.e("SERVICE","OFF");
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i'm not using the app it's being closed by itself and receiver is no longer wroking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return START_STICKY in `onStartCommand()` to keep `Service` working.

You can also set your `Service` as a **foreground** `Service` but this require showing notification in the status bar which may not be a bad idea. [Here is an example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).

**Update**

It probably would be even better if you register your `BroadcastReceiver` in AndroidManifest.xml and start `Service` work from receiver when system wake it up.

Comment: running service in foreground is not that good, it may cause user to become bored, so it's better that he woun't be bothered by notification

Comment: It depends, sometimes you should keep user informed about running background operation. If you hide it, kind of pretending nothing going on, user may felt cheated. It is usually a good idea for really long running operations that never ends without user action e.g. music player